# How do you resolve a Ninject dependency in the global file in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dependency-injection, ninject

I am using the Ninject and Ninject.Web assemblies with a web forms application. In the global.asax file I specify the bindings like so:

```
public class Global : NinjectHttpApplication
{
    protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

        // Vendor Briefs. 
        kernel.Bind<IVendorBriefRepository>().To<VendorBriefRepository>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IVendorBriefController>().To<VendorBriefController>().InRequestScope();

        // Search Services. 
        kernel.Bind<ISearchServicesController>().To<SearchServicesController>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<ISearchServicesRepository>().To<SearchServicesRepository>().InRequestScope();

        // Error Logging
        kernel.Bind<IErrorLogEntryController>().To<ErrorLogEntryController>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IErrorLogEntryRepository>().To<ErrorLogEntryRepository>().InRequestScope();


        return kernel;
    }
}
```

Then in my pages I simply have to make them inherit from `Ninject.Web.PageBase`. Then I can set up properties on the code behind pages and put the `[inject]` attribute over it.

```
[inject]
public IVendorBriefController vendorBriefController { get; set; }
```

This works great. But now I need to do some dependency injection in the Global.asax file itself. I need an instance of `IErrorLogEntryController` in my `Application_Error` event. How do I resolve this and use my specified binding for the abstract type?

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IErrorLogEntryController = ???;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do the same thing in your Global class

```
[Inject]
public IErrorLogEntryController ErrorLogEntryController { get; set; }
```

NinjectHttpApplication injects itself after the kernel is created.

Comment: I had tried this at very first, but we were using an old version of Ninject.Web. After updating the assemblies, this worked. Thanks!

Comment: That's a better answer than mine. Very nice!

Answer (score 5):

If you're using the [Ninject.Web library](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web) for ASP.NET WebForms, you should just be able to get the kernel from the [KernelContainer](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web/blob/master/src/Ninject.Web/KernelContainer.cs) static class. In this library, the KernelContainer class seems to be the starting point for service location using Ninject.

Once you have the kernel, you can get any dependency you need.

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IErrorLogEntryController = KernelContainer.Kernel.Get<IErrorLogEntryController>();
}
```

Comment: When I type `this.` I'm not seeing Kernel as a property... I even tried casting it. `((NinjectHttpApplication)this).` and still no property called Kernel. The link you provided looks like it is in the Ninject.Mvc namespace. I am using Ninject.Web (a library for web forms). But, I do see how to fix this. I can just add the kernel as a public property in my global file. Thank you.

Comment: I modified your answer to reflect this small difference and accepted it :)

Comment: Thanks for accepting, but I don't think you need to create a property. You can just get the kernel from the static KernelContainer class.

Comment: @Chevex: Doesn't that property you added end up being null whenever the event handler runs?  I believe the CreateKernel method only runs once on AppDomain startup, but the Global Object will be recreated on every request?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I don't see this static class anywhere in the Ninject.Web namespace. @qes I'm not sure I haven't actually tested this yet. Hmmmm, maybe I jumped the gun. I wish I could find this KernelContainer.

Comment: Bingo. Looks like the compiled DLL in the downloads section is not updated code. I am downloading the source and compiling it now. Thaks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

**Global.cs:**

```
        HttpContext.Current.Application["UnityContainer"] = System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(EFUnitOfWork));
```