# How to receive this Json from Web API?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I have this structure..

Cliente Side <-> Web Api Front <-> Web Api Back -> DataBase

So, When my Web Api Back send me the Json , I don´t know how to get the results.

I am not showing the connection with database.

On the Web Api Front, the line  `var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;` gives me the Json Array with all the correct values. But I don´t know how send this to the ApiCall on the Client Side.

What do I have to put on the Return?

[Service calling the Web Api Front]

```
public class ApiCall
{
    static readonly string ApiUrl = "http://Localhost:1762/api/{0}/{1}?nomePesquisa={2}&nomeMae={3}&nomePai={4}&dtNasc={5}&nrg={6}&ncpf={7}";


    //buscar os dados com os parametros digitados
    public async Task<T> GetResponse<T>(string controller, string method, string nomepesquisa, 
        string nomemae, string nomepai, string dtnasc, string nrg, string ncpf) where T : class
    {
        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        //Definide o Header de resultado para JSON, para evitar que seja retornado um HTML ou XML
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var urllink = string.Format(ApiUrl, controller, method, nomepesquisa, nomemae, nomepai, dtnasc, nrg, ncpf);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(urllink);

        //Lê a string retornada
        var JsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
            return null;

        //Converte o resultado Json para uma Classe utilizando as Libs do Newtonsoft.Json
        var rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonResult);
        return rootobject;
    }

}
```

[Web Api Front calling Web Api Back]

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Envolvidos")]
public IEnumerable<Envolvido> GetEnvolv(string nomePesquisa, string nomeMae, string nomePai, string dtNasc
   , string nRG, string nCPF)
{

    DataSet lretorno = new DataSet();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://Localhost:1762/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // Usage
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/nomes/Envolvidos?nomePesquisa="+nomePesquisa+"&nomeMae="+nomeMae+"&nomePai="+nomePai+"&dtNasc="+dtNasc+"&nrg="+nRG+"&ncpf="+nCPF+"").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            //Envolvido envolvidoResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Envolvido>(data);
            return data.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Envolvido
        {

        });

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase);
        }


        //return WHATTTTT?? ;

    }

}
```

[WebApi Back]

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Envolvidos")]
public IEnumerable<Envolvido> GetEnvolv(string nomePesquisa, string nomeMae, string nomePai, string dtnasc
    , string nRG, string nCPF)
{

    DataSet lretorno = new DataSet();

    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        OracleDataReader reader = null;
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd = new OracleCommand("MOBILE.XAPIMANDADOMOBILE.BUSCAPOSSIVEISCANDIDATOSPF", connection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //variáveis entrada            
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivnome",nomePesquisa));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivmae", nomeMae));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivpai", nomePai));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivdatanasc", dtnasc));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("ivrg", nRG));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("icpf", nCPF));
        //variáveis de saida          
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("oretorno", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("qretorno", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        //CRIO A LISTA
        lretorno.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "BUSCAPOSSIVEISCANDIDATOSPF");
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();


        //CARREGO O DATASET E TRANSFORMO PARA IENUMERABLE E RETORNO SEUS VALORES PRO JSON
        return lretorno.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Envolvido
        {
            SUSPID = Convert.ToInt32(row["SUSPID"]),
            IVNOME = Convert.ToString(row["SUSPNOME"]),
            IVMAE = Convert.ToString(row["SUSPMAE"]),
            IVPAI = Convert.ToString(row["SUSPPAI"]),
            IVDATANASC = Convert.ToString(row["SUSPDATANASC"]).Replace(" 00:00:00", ""),
            IVRG = Convert.ToString(row["RG"]),
            ICPF = Convert.ToString(row["CPF"]),
            MANDADO = Convert.ToInt16(row["TEMMANDADO"]),
            OCORRENCIA = Convert.ToInt16(row["TEMOCORRENCIA"]),

        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to make any changes to the result in the Web API Front before sending it to client?

Comment: @Nkosi Yes !! With this line return data.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Envolvido
                {

                }); , i am getting all the values 0 or null, because this select is wrong

Comment: @Nkosi Also, i triend another one return data.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Envolvido { SUSPID = Convert.ToInt32("SUSPID"),                         IVNOME = Convert.ToString("SUSPNOME"), IVMAE = Convert.ToString("SUSPMAE"),IVPAI = Convert.ToString("SUSPPAI"), IVDATANASC = Convert.ToString("SUSPDATANASC").Replace(" 00:00:00", ""), IVRG = Convert.ToString("RG"), ICPF = Convert.ToString("CPF"), MANDADO = Convert.ToInt16("TEMMANDADO"), OCORRENCIA = Convert.ToInt16("TEMOCORRENCIA"), }); BUT i got a error System.FormatException was unhandled by user code HResult=-2146233033

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you resolve a Ninject dependency in the global file in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955519/how-do-you-resolve-a-ninject-dependency-in-the-global-file-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API Back end is returning `IEnumerable<Envolvido>`

When Web Api Front end calls Web Api Backend it just needs to deserialize it to something that is assignable to `IEnumerable<Envolvido>`, be it a List, Collection, Array...etc

```
//...other code removed for brevity
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var data = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Envolvido>>().Result;
    return data;
}
//...other code removed for brevity
```